# How do I disable email sending or route to other email account in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-online

I'm migrating a site from SharePoint 2013 to Office 365. Want to ensure that no emails/notifications are sent to production user during migration.
What options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [ShareGate](https://en.share-gate.com/) for migration. Below are the steps I followed during the migration -

1. Add email routing rule in the online exchange like, if there are certain addresses, emails should be redirected to a common mailbox. For example, if any email has the address sp_redirect@mycompany.com in TO or CC then the email should be routed to test@mycompany.com
2. Add sp_redirect@mycompany.com (any email address that has a routing rule associated) in the CC field of the workflows which will be migrated
3. Migrate list/libraries without alerts
4. Migrate the workflows
5. After successful migration remove the email address sp_redirect@mycompany.com from the workflows. And then, add the user alerts in list/libraries. However, one thing needs to mention here is, ShareGate does not support User Aler migration from on-premise to on-line (Office 365)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to block the all outgoing mails during migration.

You can do this by removing the outgoing SMTP mail server in the account settings in Which mail client(Outlook, ThunderBird, etc...) your user configured their mail accounts.

Refer the url of mail configuration screenshot of outlook below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VqXg.png